# Single pole on/off switch with 3 wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a metal junction box in the kitchen of my 1968 home.  This jbox contains 2 lights switches that I want to replace.
[image]

One switch is a 3 way that is for the overhead light/fan that can also be turned on/off by another switch.  That had one common wire that was yellow and 2 blue wires.  I just wired the new switch exactly as the old and it’s working correctly.
[image]

However, I thought the seconds switch would be a single pole because it only turns on an outside light.  I bought a single pole that has 2 terminals.  Unfortunately, when I pulled out the single pole switch it has 3 wires.  1 yellow which I believe is the common wire, is in a push-in on the back and 2 red wires.  One of the red wires is in a push-in and the other is on the terminal.

So, do I need a different on/off switch because I don’t know how to get 3 wires on a switch with only 2 terminals, no push-in.  I sincerely appreciate any advice you can give me.

Comment: In the case you describe the switch contact is being used to connect two wires and not to provide a certain function like the third wire on a 3-way switch. The yellow on this simple switch is not called a "common". A simple switch has a line hot wire attached to one contact and a switched hot to the other.  A 3-way switch has one *contact* called the "common" but a wire connected to the common is not called the common wire.

Comment: One of the two red wires is *probably* the line hot and the other is a short piece of wire going to another switch in this same box. Is that what you see?

Comment: I used the word probably above because there is another possibile reason for having two wires connected to one terminal of a simple switch. That other reason would be if this one simple switch were controlling two different light fixtures. What is your arrangement?

Comment: The 3 wires coming from the single pole on/off switch seem to be as follows: one red wire is going up through the box through the galv conduit on the left side, that would probably be going to the light fixture outside.  The other red wire is going through the conduit on the bottom of the box, there is a lower outlet near there.  The yellow wire goes up the conduit on the right side of the box.

Comment: Then more investigation would be needed to determine which of the three wires is the line hot, but this is not necessary to reconnect to the new switch. As the answer says connect the two red wires to a short piece of wire and connect the other end to one terminal ofvthe switch. Connectbthe yellow wire to the other contact. Easier still would be to connect both red wires to the same contact, if the new switch allows that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Jim!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two reds are connected together internally in the switch.  This usually is done to daisy chain the hot to another device, but it could be separate feeds to multiple lights.

The most universal  answer is to get a +/-4" piece of solid wire (not white, green or gray) to connect to the new switch, then connect that wire and the two reds together with a properly sized wire connector.

Alternately if you have a switch with terminal plates (like this receptacle) [image]
you can lay one wire on each side of the screw under the clamp. (Those  wires are stripped back a little too much.)

Comment: I think I’m starting to understand.  One red wire brings power to the switch and the other takes it on to another receptacle.  So, are those both hot wires?  This ties in to what I’ve seen in some of the other outlet receptacles where I didn’t find a single cut wire under the terminal but one long wire with the coating removed at the terminal point where it connects and loops around.  Wouldn’t that be the same idea?  Powering the outlet and then going on to another.

Comment: So i have 2 options:1) buy a 4” length of 14 ga. Insulated copper wire, any color except white, green or gray. Connect that wire to the terminal.  Then pigtail the end of that wire with the 2 red wires that were previously on the old terminal and cap them with the proper sized electrical nut and stick them in the box.  Or 2) connect both ends of the red wires to the same terminal, one on each side.  With either option I would have yo connect my yellow wire to the other terminal on the switch.  What is the yellow wire?  On outlets I’ve mostly seen red and white wires.

Comment: If the old switch worked, then this should too, even though you do not know what the various wires are connected to. It would be better to know, but if you don't have test equipment this is a semi-reasonable way to proceed.

Comment: You could get a "non-contact" tester which could give some information. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-2-Piece-Non-Contact-Voltage-Tester-with-Laser-Pointer-and-GFCI-Outlet-Tester-Tool-Set-NCVT5KIT/309039693

Comment: So with the breaker off, connect the wires as you show you understand. Then turn the breaker back on and see if the switch works. Be careful not to touch the contacts with the breaker on!  You really could do this more safely if you had the non-contact tester to verify that the switch is not live.

Comment: I have not turned the power to that circuit breaker back on since I started this a few days ago.  While the 3 way side is connected and working, I’ve left the old single switch in there until I knew what to do.  I can live without a few lights and outlets for a few days.  I will buy one of the non-contact testers.  I still have several more outlets and switches to change so it will be good to have.

Comment: Emmeline, at this point you should formally accept the answer of @NoSparksPlease. Also get a plug-in receptacle tester.

Comment: @Emmeline for clarity Re: "Or 2) connect both ends of the red wires to the same terminal, one on each side", as far as I know you can only do this if there is a plate (essentially a square washer) behind the screw head.

Comment: We don't know (or really care) which end of the switch is fed with the hot and which is the switch-leg out to light(s). The hot could be (1)one of the reds in, the other red unswitched hot leading to  another device, and the yellow the switched hot, or (2) yellow hot into box, and two reds taking different paths to two separate light fixtures or switched receptacles.  Either way the replacement switch wires exactly the same.

Comment: The most likely (but not critical) situation is option (1) since in the US black and red are traditionally hots, and often odd colors are pulled into conduits for switch-legs so you can easily differentiate hots from switch-legs. The NEC only reserves green, white, gray,  and sometimes orange colors for specific purposes, so yellow is a "hot" color, but not specifically switched or not..

Comment: And finally re:"one long wire with the coating removed at the terminal point where it connects and loops around", I had one particularly ornery inspector give me grief about that method not being included in the installation instructions, so he claimed he could ding me. He didn't, but warned he would in the future.